# Stronger Active Record IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can we get Active Record to create more complex IDs that are not just the natural numbers (1, 2, 3 ...). I'm not sure if I should be using database IDs to identify objects, but I am now and it would be pretty insecure to have them like this in production.

Comment: Maybe something like `slug` would help? You can keep on using `id` as the primary key, but use another column for all other things. So, all of you have to do is just generate a unique `slug` that will identify that object and stop using `id` to get that object for everything in public.

Comment: @amree so a slug basically maps some number to an ID number? If you don't mind, can you provide an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty insecure"?

Comment: There is nothing inherently insecure about auto-incrementing record IDs. Most websites use them. Security is a concept you define and build on top of your data. It's possible that non-sequential IDs could be part of your solution, but there is no reason it has to be.

Comment: @meagar okay thanks. I'm used to seeing long UIDs in MongoDB which I thought would deter people from trying to attack the system by just incrementing the ID in the route (even though there's security to prevent that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets just say you want to use a column called `slug` for an object called `Post`.

- Create a `slug` column for that table
- Create a `before_create` method in `Post` model that will generate a unique `slug` value before saving the record. Maybe do some checking to ensure it’s unique
- Replace anything that’s public facing to use `Post.find_by(slug: id)` instead of `Post.find(id)`.
- Ensure any url generation will use something like this: `post_path(id: post.slug)` so that it won't put the `id` the URL.